# AttributeError: 'Seq' object has no attribute 'islower' in ProtParam module of Biopython

Tags: python, biopython

I tried using ProteinAnalysis function or ProtParam module but is throwing error.
Any help is appreciated.
[image: no attribute 'tostring']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ProteinAnalysis`expects a `string` (from which a `Seq` object will be created) while you're already passing it a `Seq` object.

The quick solution is: convert your sequence to a `string`:

```
amino_acid_seq = ProteinAnalysis(str(seq_record.seq))
```

But if you look at the docs you will see that there are options for directly reading your sequence as a string.

Comment: Raises the question though, maybe `Seq` should have an `.isupper()` and `.islower()` method